# Grafana show value at time index in Stat graph on hover

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have multiple grafana Stat panels in a combined dashboard that look great and do the job well
I would like them to show some context though as currently I see the current value and an area graph but other than the current value the high and low points are a mystery. I would very much like to be able to hover in the graph area and see a timestamp/datetime and a value at that time

This is how all the other graph types work

I can see the Legend functionality that can place text on hover that can accept variables
and should do what I want but the documentation is terrible and i cannot find out how to show the current value at that time index or the current value or anything really

This is the panel and metric config
[image: Grafana stat panel with metric visible]

[image: Legend for graph showing the metric address no value]

The data I am getting passed into grafana is just a value that changes over time so any time index is getting set automatically by the Stat graph. The Stat graph is pretty much Auto everything except unit set to Celsius and some thresholds set for different colors

The data is in the following format for this graph returned from a metrics endpoint

```
espeasy_device_BME280{valueName="Temperature"} 29.99
```

(Device name) (Sensor) (Value name from sensor) (Current value)

Does anyone know if this is possible? I might need to add a timestamp into the metrics endpoint potentially if I cant reuse the internal grafana timestamp that the graph is using? and how to achieve it please? ideally something like
T {value} {DateTime} which i can plug into the Legend field?

I've looked at the documentation of Legend and the Stat panel in the Grafana doco and tried searching for something similar but haven't seen anything

I've tried entering the following values in the legend field but they don't get parsed as variables just text

```
$__interval 
$__interval_ms
espeasy_device_BME280{valueName="Temperature"}[$__interval] {{Temperature}}
T {{espeasy_device_BME280{valueName="Temperature"}[$__interval]}}
```

The last seems like the closest to working it at least shows "T " on hover so its getting parsed but then removed or returns null i guess

Comment: Use `Time series` panel type https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/time-series/

Comment: Are you saying the Stat panel will never work to display values in the backing graph?
If i do use the time series panel how do I get the current value to display similar to the stat panel?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/stat-panel/ https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/time-series/

Comment: "I've looked at the documentation of Legend and the Stat panel in the Grafana doco and tried searching for something similar but haven't seen anything" Yes i can use a time series graph, thanks it looks very little like a stat panel though it does have a useable tooltop it doesn't answer any of the questions I've asked, could you try answering any of the questions next time? it might help make a decision, explain things for others and reduce wasted effort